# Unable to boot ubuntu 16.04 tried all the intenet option no luck

Tags: 16.04

Gents

My ubuntu 16.04 ubuntu laptop shutdown suddenly and when restarted I got this error 
(Initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system. Tried to exit but give me long error at the end No onit found .try passing init=bootarg tried init = bootrage no hope tried to boot from usb and do the sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1 fix error but still the problem same.

Note 1-when start and try to boot when press ESC give this error /init: line 11 : cant open /dev/sr0: No medium found

Note 2- when I tried to boot using boot repair bootable usb give me(failsfae). And open the ubuntu via the USB .thank you